# Fires EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone

Hi I am trying to implement Captcha functionality. The following code, i have used for generating random word:

```
-(void) createCaptchaWord{
        lettersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z", nil];
        randomWord = @"";

    for(NSUInteger i=0;i<5;i++){
        NSUInteger randomNumber = arc4random()%[lettersArray count];
        randomWord = [randomWord stringByAppendingString:[lettersArray objectAtIndex:randomNumber]];
        //randomWord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",randomWord,[lettersArray objectAtIndex:randomNumber]];
    }

    NSString *captchaUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",CommonFunctions.captchaImgUrl,randomWord];
    UIImage *captchaImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:captchaUrl]]];

    [captchaImgView setImage:captchaImage];
}
```

The problem is with the variable randomWord. I can access this variable inside the method named "createCaptchaWord". There is another function to save all the information entered. In that method, when i tried to access the variable "randomWord", I got the exception EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Then i enabled NSZombie. Thus i got the following message in the console:

**-[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4656c10**

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Regards,
Sreelash

Comment: How is randomWord declared in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to retain the value  which will be assigned to the `randomWord` variable with either using `retain` or a setter method (when it's a property) like `self.randomWord = ...`